# CSS background image repeat not displaying

Tags: css

```
background: url("/Img/chic/gradient.JPG") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
color: White;
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
font-size: 11px;
font-weight: bold;
margin-bottom: 1px;
padding: 2px 0 3px 15px;
position: relative;
text-decoration: none;
vertical-align: text-bottom;
width: 100px;
```

That is the outputted CSS on the button gotten from Firebug. The background is not displaying however.

This is how the CSS is declared in the code:

```
.navigationTab
{
    position:relative;
    color:White;    
    width:100px;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:1px;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:2px 0px 3px 15px; 
    vertical-align:text-bottom;
    text-decoration:none;
    display: block;
    /*filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#2273ba', endColorstr='#1B62A0', iOrientation=1); /* for IE */
    /*background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#2273ba), to(#1B62A0)); /* for webkit browsers */
    /*background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #2273ba,  #1B62A0); /* for firefox 3.6+ */
    background: url(/Img/chic/gradient.JPG) repeat-x;

}
```

Am I declaring the background wrong?

HTML:

```
<a href="/Extranet/mvc/Indications.cfc/rates/8bfe5685-5de1-4cba-b5bd-9c128fb513bb" class="navigationTab" id="ctl00_ratesLink">
    <img src="/Extranet/img/chic/plugin.png" style="vertical-align: text-bottom;"><span style="padding-left: 5px;">Rates </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Try entering the absolute path of the gradient.jpg file and see if that works. And shouldn't the url be enclosed in ' ' ?

Comment: What would the absolute path look like? -- everything up to like C:/?

Comment: This .css doc's containing folder is located in the same level as /Img.

Comment: @slandau The absolute path would be the full url to the image.

Comment: @slandau - It would also help if you include the HTML for the element where you are applying the style and the browser/version where you are seeing the issue.

Comment: It will be better if you put the sample code online, then we can easily check where is the mistake. Usually this because the path is wrong. Please pay attention some server/system is use case-sensitive.

Comment: I'm using the full path copied from Visual Studio and I'm still not seeing anything.

Comment: The path copied from visual studio probably isn't the correct one. You want the URL to the image file. First test that url in a browser to see if the image comes up to confirm it is right, then try pasting it in your CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked that the image path is correct?

One thing to watch out for is that if the style is defined in an external style sheet, relative image paths are relative to the .css file not the HTML page.

Comment: Nothing jumps out as being obviously wrong with it, but if you include the HTML of the element it is applied to it might help us diagnose it.